# Is this sentenced to call constructor?

Tags: java, variable-declaration

```
public class TestBikes {
public static void main(String[] args){
Bicycle bike01, bike02, bike03;

bike01 = new Bicycle(20, 10, 1);
bike02 = new MountainBike(20, 10, 5, "Dual");
bike03 = new RoadBike(40, 20, 8, 23);

bike01.printDescription();
bike02.printDescription();
bike03.printDescription();
}
}
```

can line 3 (Bicycle bike01, bike02, bike03) and its 3 instance be rewritten as

```
Bicycle bike01 = new Bicycle(20, 10, 1);
Bicycle bike02 = new MountainBike(20, 10, 5, "Dual");
Bicycle bike03 = new RoadBike(40, 20, 8, 23);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it ? (and please fix the tags to include `java`)

Comment: If the two extends Bicycle and they have appropriate constructor, then I don't see why not

Comment: i cant, only have part of the code. the other clases are not availablel.

Comment: @Leonne: So write your own test classes.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking whether you can initialize a variable as part of its declaration, e.g.:

```
Bicycle bike01 = new Bicycle(20, 10, 1);
```

rather than

```
Bicycle bike01;

bike01 = new Bicycle(20, 10, 1);
```

Yes, you can do that, and people commonly do. It doesn't change the resulting program.

---

Side note: When you find yourself writing variable names like `bike01`, `bike02`, etc., consider using an array or similar instead.

Comment: oh now i get it... thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course , In the first case you just define them at the first then you initialize them but in the second case you define and initialize them simultaneously